# Compiling Pascalscript in 64 bit mode, events not working?

Tags: delphi, pascalscript

I have downloaded and started playing with Pascalscript and its sample programs.

I have come across a problem with interfacing to Forms using the Forms access sample script.

It works in 32 bit mode, in 64 bit mode no events get triggered.

That is, a buttons onpress event never calls the pascalscript onpress code.

I am using Delphi 10 Seattle on windows 7 pro.

Any ideas on how to get scripts working right on the 64 bit platform?

Comment: Is this library supported on 64 bit

Comment: @David Scripting all seems to work under 64 bits. You can create a form and it all comes up OK. It just seems to be the callback events that don't work.

Comment: Delphi 10 Seatlle Win64 compiler is broken. It may have nothing to do with PascalScript. Did you try with XE8? Did you install the temporary fix for Win64 platform? http://blog.synopse.info/post/2015/10/05/Delphi-10-Seattle-Win64-compiler-Heisenbug%3A-unusable-target You may have to wait for the upcoming official "Update 1" to have the RTL dcu also fixed.

Comment: @Arnud Thanks for that but I just tried XE8 and it does the same. Looks like a bug in the PascalScript runtime.

Comment: Have you asked the vendor for support?

Comment: @DAvid I tracked down the bit of code in the runtime that does it and the 64 bit code is missing, it is assembler so finding a 64 equivalent would be problematic without in depth knowledge of what delphi does. So I went on Github and posted an issue. I just got a reply saying its not going to be done. Looks like they stopped supporting it.

Comment: Time to fork it and fix it!!

Comment: Pardon my curiousity but which PascalScript do you mean, the RemObjects one or another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well seeing as no one had an answer to this I had to do the hard work myself.

So the problem was empty prolog code for x64 in the conversion from delphi to pascalscript method calling which was written in assembler. The empty method handler was called "MyAllMethodhandler" in the uPSruntime unit and my code solution is as follows

```
function MyAllMethodsHandler2(Self:PScriptMethodInfo; const Stack:PPointer; _EDX,_ECX:Pointer):Integer; forward;

{$ifdef CPUX64}
procedure MyAllMethodsHandler;
//  On entry:
//  RCX = Self pointer
//  RDX, R8, R9 = param1 .. param3
//  STACK = param4... paramcount
asm
  PUSH  R9
  MOV   R9,R8     // R9:=_ECX
  MOV   R8,RDX    // R8:=_EDX
  MOV   RDX, RSP  // RDX:=Stack
  SUB   RSP, 20h
  CALL MyAllMethodsHandler2
  ADD   RSP, 20h  //Restore stack
  POP   R9
end;
{$else}

procedure MyAllMethodsHandler;   //original x86 code
//  On entry:
//  EAX = Self pointer
//  EDX, ECX = param1 and param2
//  STACK = param3... paramcount
asm
  push 0
  push ecx
  push edx
  mov edx, esp
  add edx, 16 // was 12
  pop ecx
  call MyAllMethodsHandler2
  pop ecx
  mov edx, [esp]
  add esp, eax
  mov [esp], edx
  mov eax, ecx
end;
{$endif}
```

Not sure if this will work with everything but seems to work for at least 2 parameters.

I'll post it as a comment on GitHub, I can't really fix it directly as I have made extensive changes to the whole of Pascal script so it supports complex math.

Comment: The solution works for event register with `RegisterProperty` but fail for event register with `RegisterEventPropertyHelper`.  For example: `TStringList.OnChange` event.  Assign an event to `TStringList.OnChange` trigger `TSTRINGLISTONCHANGE_W` and it cause access violation in Win64 runtime